# Naming clusters in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using the iris dataset in R. I clustered the data using K-means; the output is the variable km.out. However, I cannot find an easy way to assign the cluster numbers (1-3) to a species (versicolor, setosa, virginica). I created a manual way to do it but I have to set the seed and it's very manual. There has to be a better way to do it. Any thoughts?

**Here is what I did manually:**

```
for (i in 1:length(km.out$cluster)) {
  if (km.out$cluster[i] == 1) {
    km.out$cluster[i] = "versicolor"
  }
}
for (i in 1:length(km.out$cluster)) {
  if (km.out$cluster[i] == 2) {
    km.out$cluster[i] = "setosa"
  }
}
for (i in 1:length(km.out$cluster)) {
  if (km.out$cluster[i] == 3) {
    km.out$cluster[i] = "virginica"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jason, your question is a bit vague because it suggests that you'd like to rename the cluster names `1` `2` and `3` with species names, which can't really be what you want to do given that there is no 1:1 correspondance, right? I added two lines of code in my answer, which assigns the *most frequent species in each cluster* as well as the *most frequently assigned cluster* per species, regardless of how common a species is in your dataset. If that doesn't help, you need to state your question more precisely, "naming clusters in R" doesn't seem the best choice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R is a vectorized language, the following one-liner is equivalent to the code in the question.

```
km.out$cluster <- c("versicolor", "setosa", "virginica")[km.out$cluster]
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. The clusters created by `kmeans` will not match the `Species` exactly and there is no guarantee that clusters 1, 2, 3 will match the order of the species in `iris`. Also as you noted, the results will vary depending on the value of the seed. For example,

```
set.seed(42)
iris.km <- kmeans(scale(iris[, -5]), 3)
table(iris.km$cluster, iris$Species)
#    
#     setosa versicolor virginica
#   1     50          0         0
#   2      0         39        14
#   3      0         11        36
```

Cluster 1 is exactly associated with setosa, but cluster 2 combines versicolor and virginica as does cluster 3.

Comment: Hi @dcarlson, I just realized your answer is nearly the same as mine. If it stays up, you might like to add the last line of my answer to yours (which does the actual assignment [of the most frequent species per cluster])

Comment: Your example illustrates another problem with the request. The same species can be assigned to more than one cluster.

Comment: I am looking to see if there is a way to optimize the outputted table to assign cluster names to the cluster columns. For example, if there is a species that was vastly more common than another, then using the row max or column max would not be effective. Is there an optimization technique to match the cluster numbers to the cluster names based on our estimates? I know this is best done with regression but I want to try it in clustering.

Comment: I don't understand the need to name the clusters. In this example, the confusion table indicates that (50 + 39 + 36) = 125 out of 150 or 83% of the specimens are correctly identified. What is the purpose of calling cluster 3, virginica when 23% of the observations in that cluster are not virginica? Likewise most of the cluster 2 specimens are versicolor, but 26% are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can recode the cluster number and add it back to the original data with:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(iris, 
       cluster = case_when(km.out$cluster == 1 ~ "versicolor",
                           km.out$cluster == 2 ~ "setosa",
                           km.out$cluster == 3 ~ "virginica"))
```

Alternatively you can use a vector translation approach to recoding a vector with elucidate::translate()

```
remotes::install_github("bcgov/elucidate") #if elucidate isn't installed yet
library(dplyr)
library(elucidate)

mutate(iris, 
       cluster = translate(km.out$cluster, 
                           old = c(1:3), 
                           new =  c("versicolor", 
                                    "setosa", 
                                    "virginica")))
```

Comment: the advantage of adding the cluster variable back to the data source like this with mutate is that you can easily compare the clusters to the species column

Answer (score 0):

if you want to *assign the cluster numbers (1-3) to a species (versicolor, setosa, virginica)*, you'll likely not have a 1:1 correspondence. But you could *assign the most frequent species in each cluster* like this:

```r
data(iris)

# k-means clustering
set.seed(5834)
km.out <- kmeans(iris[,1:4], centers = 3)

# associate species with clusters
(cmat <- table(Species = iris[,5], cluster = km.out$cluster))
#>             cluster
#> Species       1  2  3
#>   setosa     33 17  0
#>   versicolor  0  4 46
#>   virginica   0  0 50

# find the most-frequent species in each cluster
setNames(rownames(cmat)[apply(cmat, 2, which.max)], colnames(cmat))
#>           1           2           3 
#>    "setosa"    "setosa" "virginica"

# find the most-frequent assigned cluster per species
setNames(colnames(cmat)[apply(cmat, 1, which.max)], rownames(cmat))
#>     setosa versicolor  virginica 
#>        "1"        "3"        "3"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>